# can't call onactivity result function after child activity is finished

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using following codes.

```
 addNewReceipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddReceipt.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("receiptList", receipts);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, RECEIPT_ADD);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) 
    {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
     if (requestCode == RECEIPT_ADD)
     {
        receipts = (ArrayList<Receipt>) data.getSerializableExtra("receiptList");
        addReceiptsInListView();
     }
    }
    }
```

The code for AddReceipt class is as follow,

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("receiptList", receipts);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data); 
        super.finish();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onCreateCall()
    {

          done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
          {  //receiptAddBtn
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    String error = "";
                    Receipt receipt = new Receipt();
                    receipt.comments = comments.getText().toString();
                    receipt.referenceNo = receiptNo.getText().toString();
                    receipt.image = imageSelected;
                    if (receipt.image == null || receipt.referenceNo == "" )
                    {
                        error = "Please input Receipt No. and attach Image";
                        displayAlert(error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        receipts.add(receiptCounter,receipt);
                                              finish();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

The problem is, when the activity is finished... and i pass this receipt, in my previous class from which i call this activity `public synchronized void onActivityResult` Never works.

The back button is not ending activity either.

Please tell me where i am wrong,.

Best Regards

Comment: Does it even enter onActivityResult at all? (irrespective of the response code etc)

Comment: is `onActivityResult(...)` getting called?  maybe with a different `resultCode` or not even at all?

Comment: wasnt calling at all.. oh great, it worked with Below code and now its same as before want to find lol !!!

Comment: any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("receiptList", receipts);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data); 
        super.finish();
    }
```